# Ignoring null fields in Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have some data that I have to serialize to JSON. I'm using JSON.NET. My code structure is similar to this:

```
public struct structA
{
    public string Field1;
    public structB Field2;
    public structB Field3;
}

public struct structB
{
    public string Subfield1;
    public string Subfield2;
}
```

Problem is, my JSON output needs to have ONLY `Field1` OR `Field2` OR `Field3` - it depends on which field is used (i.e. not null). 
By default, my JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Field1": null,
    "Field2": {"Subfield1": "test1", "Subfield2": "test2"},
    "Field3": {"Subfield1": null, "Subfield2": null},
}
```

I know I can use `NullValueHandling.Ignore`, but that gives me JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "Field2": {"Subfield1": "test1", "Subfield2": "test2"},
    "Field3": {}
}
```

And what I need is this:

```
{
    "Field2": {"Subfield1": "test1", "Subfield2": "test2"},
}
```

Is there simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net)

Comment: Because you are using `struct`s, the only field that may have a null value is Field1. If you want Field2 and Field3 to be nulllable, you need to make them reference types instead of value types.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes you need to use `JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`.

But because [structs are value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you need to mark Field2, Field3 **nullable** to get the expected result:

```
public struct structA
{
    public string Field1;
    public structB? Field2;
    public structB? Field3;
}
```

Or just use classes instead of structs.

Documentation: [**NullValueHandling Enumeration**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm)

Comment: for more info see http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx

Answer (score 77):

You can also apply the JsonProperty attribute to the relevant properties and set the null value handling that way. Refer to the `Reference` property in the example below:

*Note: The `JsonSerializerSettings` will override the attributes.*

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty( NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore )]
    public int? Reference { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```