# How to get current used network adapter

Tags: c#, ip-address, mac-address

Now I am trying to get network adapter in use among of several network adapters on my machine so that I can get ip address, mac address and adapter name of the network adapter. But I am not having any luck.
What I found the solution for it is [Get current network adapter in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548435/get-current-network-adapter-in-use#answer-46637015).
I dont think it is for .Net framework project but ASP.NET Core.

My code is below.

```
public void GetIpAndMacAddress()
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        // Only consider Ethernet network interfaces
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet &&
            nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = nic.GetIPProperties();
            foreach (var ip in adapterProperties.UnicastAddresses) 
            {
                if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    IPAddress = ip.Address.ToString();
            }
            string hexMac = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString(),
                   regex = "(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})",
                   replace = "$1:$2:$3:$4:$5:$6";
            IPv4InterfaceProperties p = adapterProperties.GetIPv4Properties();

            netAdapterName = nic.Name;
            MACAddress = Regex.Replace(hexMac, regex, replace);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in use"?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica, thanks for your interests, it means that the current used network adapter I am using to connect to internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/621702/3907561

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following should help you.

```
NetworkInterface[] networks = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

var activeAdapter = networks.First(x=> x.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
                    && x.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel
                    && x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up 
                    && x.Name.StartsWith("vEthernet") == false);
```

The search is based on eliminating Network Adapters that are neither [Loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=netframework-4.8) (Commonly used for testing) or [Tunnel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=netframework-4.8)(commonly used for secure connection between private networks). Operational Status ensures that the Network interface is up and is is able to transmit data packets. The "vEthernet" is naming convention commonly used by Windows for [Hyper-V Virtual Network Adapters](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check it and will let you know

Comment: I think it is what I wanted, Could you explain more about search terms?

Comment: @JSGuru I have updated the answer with brief description .Hope that helped

Comment: Hi Anu Viswan, I appreciated your help.