# Ignore deserialize when no such property exist

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm consuming a private web service , which is not in my control.

i'm consuming a login service, This is class about to deseralized the result

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string msg { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "data", IsRequired = false)]
    public LoginDTO LoginInfo{ get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class LoginDTO 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }

}
```

Here what i tried

```
public async Task<BaseDTO> InsertString(MyObject insertParameters)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _client = new HttpClient())
            {
                _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseServiceUri);
                _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpContent insertHttpcontent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(insertObject));

                var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri(baseAccessPoint, UriKind.Relative), insertHttpcontent);

                //Throws exception when its invalid
                //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var responseResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseDTO>(responseResult, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    Error = JsonDeserializeErrorHandler,
                });
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

**If the login credentials are true service is returning the LoginInfo details ,else it will not provide any information just the status,msg and code.**

The problem is the Json Deseralizer always try to Deseralize everything even if tried to set ignore null value , but doesn't seems working. As my service is not returning null, It will not provide the object itself. Currently i handle using JsonDeserializeErrorHandler setting errorhandled property to true. 
I have referenced [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-it-is-null-using-json-net)

JsonResult When success

```
{"status":"success","msg":"Welcome!!","code":"","data":{"session_token":"bdadee2cb7597fbb5ceed550ca389440","firsname":"test1","lastname":"test2"}}}}
```

JsonResult When Error

```
{"status":"warning","msg":"Incorrect Username or MPIN","code":"","data":[]}
```

**How do i overcome this scenario more gracefully**

```
    #region DeserializeErrorHandling
    private void JsonDeserializeErrorHandler(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        //var currentError = e.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
        e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in one case you get an object `{"session_token":"12", ...}` and an empty array `[]` in another for `data` property. Empty array is not *null*. That means that you can not use the same type for deserializing such JSON.

My suggestion is to use `dynamic` for `data` property and then parse this value:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseDTO
{
    // Rest of the properties

    [DataMember]
    public dynamic data { get; set; }

    public LoginDTO LoginInfo
    {
        get
        {
            var jObjectData = data as JObject;
            if (jObjectData == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                return jObjectData.ToObject<LoginDTO>();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use more logic in `LoginInfo` property. For example you could parse it based on status and etc.

Note: your success JSON is invalid, I guess it's just a copy/paste issue.

Comment: The success json in question are manually written. I will try these and will update soon , Thank you for your time.