# Hide object property when null when returning to View

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Say i have a C# Class called Vehicle:

```
public class Vehicle {
    public int VehicleNumber {get;set;}
    public string SerialNumber {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
}
```

Now this is a function in a webApi controller:

```
public string Get(){
    return new Vehicle {VehicleNumber = 1, Model = "Lexus car"}
}
```

The Json object I would receive upon sending the get request would be:

```
{ "VehicleNumber" : 1, "SerialNumber" : null, "Model" = "Lexus Car"}
```

Is there a way to omit properties that are null from the end result? so that my final result would like so:

```
{ "VehicleNumber" : 1, "Model" = "Lexus Car"}
```

Edit: This question seemse to be very similar to another question that i have not encountered untill commented on this question.

But it is not entirely identical. Is there any way that with Data Annotations i can prevent serialization of a property if the property is null?

Comment: @GiladGreen It is indeed very similar, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

After more research i have found that this question is a duplicate of this one here:

[How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net)

This question provides the answer that i need.