# Json Parse Object Null Reference

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

Json Data

```
{
    "user" : 
    {
        "name" : "asdf",
        "teamname" : "b",
        "email" : "c"
    },
    {
        "name" : "asdf",
        "teamname" : "b"
    }
}
```

Since there are no emails in 2 lines Object Null Reference exceptions.
data control

How to do field control ???

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to parse the JSON?

Comment: That's not even a valid json...

Comment: Like @Gusman pointed out, fix your json and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439479/4225626) should help you with your null handling.

Comment: Your JSON isn't a valid JSON. Your JSON should look like this:

    {
        "user" :[ 
        {
                "name" : "asdf",
                "teamname" : "b",
                "email" : "c"
        },
        {
            "name" : "asdf",
            "teamname" : "b",
            "email" : "c"
        }]
    }

Comment: And if my attention is right, this is the class you should use:



    public class User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string teamname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<User> user { get; set; }
    }

You can convert your JSON in the RootObject with this line of code:

    RootObject myObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(JSONStringVariable);