# Add JProperty to JObject only if value is not null

Tags: c#, json.net

I construct a new `JObject` instance the following way:

```
return new JObject(
    new JProperty("prop1", prop1),
    new JProperty("prop2", prop2))
```

I would like, however, to add a key/value pair only if the value is not null. E.g. if `prop1` is null, I'd like no a key/value pair `'prop1': null` to be added. Can this be done in an elegant way?

Comment: Did you check 'JsonSerializerSettings'?

Comment: @hsd It works fine, thanks. Ideally I'd like to have more control, i.e. with having the ability to do `new JPropertyIfNotNull(...)`, so I still have the ability to add null properties with `new JProperty(...)` but this is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control it in `JsonSerializerSettings`. 
Please take a look on answer [How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net)
You are creating object dynamically but solution is the same.