# How to avoid serialising specific fields when generating JSON

Tags: c#, json, constructor

I have the following C# class which contains 2 constructors:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public DataPoint(double x, double y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public DataPoint(double y, string label)
    {
        this.Y = y;
        this.Label = label;
    }

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "x")]
    public Nullable<double> X = null;

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "y")]
    public Nullable<double> Y = null;

    //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "label")]
    public string Label;
}
```

Inside my MVC Controller I need to create an instance of the `DataPoint` class and use the 2nd constructor, i.e., `public DataPoint(double y, string label)` .

I do this in the code below and then serialize the object into JSON.

```
List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>{
            new DataPoint(10, "cat 1"),
            new DataPoint(20, "cat 2")

        };

ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);
```

When I view the returned JSON it looks like this

```
[{"x":null,"y":10.0,"label":"cat 1"},{"x":null,"y":20.0,"label":"cat 2"}]
```

My problem is that I don't want the `x` element included in my JSON data.

Why is this happening when I am not instantiating the 1st constructor in the `DataPoint` class?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ShouldSerialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm#ShouldSerialize) method.

Add this to your DataPoint class

```
public bool ShouldSerializeX()
{
    return (X != null);
}
```

And then add `Formatting.Indented` to your serialization call:

```
ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: I fail to see how this solution is cleaner than the solution in the [suggested duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net). Use JsonConvert's functionality to ignore nulls rather than adding custom logic to achieve the same result.

Comment: @UncleDave It is more general, next time the property he wants to ignore might not be null but hold a different value. It works in his case and also provides an example he can use for other cases.

Comment: I agree @MBakardzhiev - for the OP's _specific_ case this is unnecessary (and likely slower due to reflection), but for the _broader_ problem space this is a great way of attacking the problem.

Comment: This answer could be **even better** if it was tweaked to include why `X` was serialised to start with (i.e. `JsonConvert` doesn't care which constructor was called - it just cares about the public properties).