# Serializing a changing C# object to JSON

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to serialize `Item` object but the `ActionItem` object would be always changing.

C# Object

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ActionItem Action { get; set; }
}

public class ActionItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialize the object above I will be getting:

```
{
   Name: null,
   Action: {
      Value: null
   }
}
```

But I am expecting it as `{ Name: null , Action: {} }`

I would like to refactor the `ActionItem` object so that it can take other format of json/schema.
E.g.

```
{
    Name : 'MyName',
    Action : 
         {
           ActName: 'Finish',
           ActType: 1
           //...might differ because this field is always changing
         }
}
```

I tried serializing, using `JsonConvert.Serialize()`, a `new Object()` and it is serialized as `{}` but I cant assign `ActionItem` object as a `new Object()`

How can I achieve my desired result for this?

**UPDATE**
I made it work somehow after watching this [snippet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YeD_7GRp2I).
I just changed the `ActionItem` to `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to serialize nulls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net)

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question correctly. I am assuming you are serializing a `new Item()`. Since, instance of class `Item` is initialized, it is returning the expected result that you are getting. Now, note that, instantiating a new instance of `Item` class *does not* instantiated a new object of type `ActionItem`. That's why you are getting `Action: {      Value: null   }`.

Comment: @V.P.Verma I want to serialize the `Item` object however serializing `ActionItem` field is different. The task  is that `ActionItem` is not just `Value` can be other property as well.