# Remove Tag from JSON String in C#

Tags: c#, json

```
{"InvPhy":[{"OpID":234,"RtID":null,"AccID":5965,"LocID":7223,"DlvrLocID":7738,"InvAccID":31345,"FscDt":"2019-05-16T00:00:00","TrDT":"2019-09-19T18:13:17+05:30","Schdl":true,"CntType":661,"DvcID":56000,"SvcUID":0,"Dtls":[{"ProdID":48456,"ProdPkgID":84947,"TrDT":"2019-09-19T18:13:09+05:30","Qty":2},{"ProdID":32382,"ProdPkgID":61198,"TrDT":"2019-09-19T18:13:17+05:30","Qty":3}]}]}
```

I have this JSON and I need to remove property RtID.

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
jo.Property("RtID").Remove();
jsonResult = jo.ToString();
```

This is not working...Pls help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore a property in class if null, using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net). (It may help, but I am not quite sure if it will fit)

Answer (score 0):

You need use [remove](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Remove.htm) method and pass field name.

```
jo.Remove("RtID");
```

Comment: jo.Remove("RtID"); is Not Working @cdev

Comment: @MainakChoudhury it works, when you apply it to the correct object

Answer (score 0):

One option would be as follow:

Consider you have the following C# classes to `deserialize` your `JSON` object to:

```
public class Dtl
{
    public int ProdID { get; set; }
    public int ProdPkgID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrDT { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

public class InvPhy
{
    public int OpID { get; set; }
    //public object RtID { get; set; }
    public int AccID { get; set; }
    public int LocID { get; set; }
    public int DlvrLocID { get; set; }
    public int InvAccID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FscDt { get; set; }
    public DateTime TrDT { get; set; }
    public bool Schdl { get; set; }
    public int CntType { get; set; }
    public int DvcID { get; set; }
    public int SvcUID { get; set; }
    public List<Dtl> Dtls { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<InvPhy> InvPhy { get; set; }
}
```

You could just remove the `RtID` property, and it would not `deserialize` the value of that property.

Here is an example of how you could `deserialize` your `JSON` to an object.  `Deserializing` to an object also makes it easier to work with in the rest of your code.

```
RootObject account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: i am re-using this class Inv, so sometimes i need the RtID and sometimes i don't - to send as a webservice request

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
   JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
   JToken token = jo.GetValue("InvPhy");
   JArray array = (token as JArray);
   JToken ob = array[0];
   (ob as JObject).Remove("RtID");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelObbject, settings);
```