# Remove sublist from list model using C# for JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm sending json format and I would like to ask if it's possible to remove a sublist from a list.
I have models like these.

```
public class lineItems
{
     public string item_name { get; set; }
     public int quantity { get; set; }
     public string price { get; set; }
     public List<subItem> subItem { get; set; }
}
public class subItem
{
     public string sub_item_name { get; set; }
     public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The json looks like this. What i'm trying to do is remove the subItem from the second item.
I tried to make the subItem null but it still displays in the json format with "subItem": [].

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tlim.png

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net ?

Comment: Thank you so much @dimitar.d .I will try this.

Comment: Hi. I tried this code
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order, settings);

it removes the null items but it seems the the subItem still cannot be removed from the json.

    {
      "item_name ": "sub_item_2",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": "84000.00",
      "subItem": [
        null
      ]
    }

Comment: Thank you so much. The link above works for me.