# C# AutoMapper MapFrom two different properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to configure AutoMapper to Conditionaly map one target property to two different source properties:

```
public class JourneyDTO
{
  public VehicleDTO vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class Journey
{
  public Car car { get; set; }
  public Bus bus { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
}

public class Bus
{
}
```

and then AutoMapper configuration:

```
.ForMember(m => m.vehicle, src => {
                    src.PreCondition(p => (p.bus != null));
                    src.MapFrom(f => f.bus);
                })

.ForMember(m => m.vehicle, src => {
                    src.PreCondition(p => (p.car!= null));
                    src.MapFrom(f => f.car);
                })
```

On my result JourneyDTO I only get vehicle filled with `car`. If there is no `car`, only `bus` on source object, then DTO `vehicle` property is null

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: I found a workaround, however trick ist to cast to object in order to compile

Comment: Do not use ForMember method. If I remember well it is not recomending by Jimmy Bogard. Remove VehicleDTO and add CarDTO and BusDTO.

If You are using NewtonSoft.Json to serialization You can ignore null values:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net

Comment: Why? What is a recommended replacement for ForMember method?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
.ForMember(
 m => m.vehicle, 
 src => src.MapFrom(o => ((o.bus != null) ? (object)o.bus : (object)o.car))
)
```