# Handling empty subclasses in API calls in ASP.NET Core with .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I've just upgraded my backend API to ASP.NET Core with .NET 6 and started getting errors if a `POST` call contains an empty subsclass.

Here's an example. My API receives `POST` calls for comment entries and the class that handles these calls looks like this:

```
public class CommentEntry
{
   [Required]
   public string Comments { get; set; }

   public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

   public File Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, this class has a `File` subclass for attachments. The `File` class looks like this:

```
public class File
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

When my API was running ASP.NET Core with .NET 5, I could send a `POST` request like the one below which sent an empty object for `attachment` property and it would work fine:

```
{
   "comments": "Hello World!",
   "entryDate: "2021-11-13T14:52",
   "attachment": {}
}
```

Now, my controller action method is rejecting this because of `!ModelState.IsValid` line.

If I change the `POST` request to the following, it then works in .NET 6 as well.

```
{
   "comments": "Hello World!",
   "entryDate: "2021-11-13T14:52",
   "attachment: {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "name": "",
      "url": ""
   }

}
```

As you can see in `CommentEntry` class, an attachment is not required.

What's the correct way to handle this scenario where I have no data for the subclass? Should I not be sending an empty object in my `POST` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the property binding doesn't like 'empty' objects. My guess is that it will try to set the property to null. However, .net 6 has a stricter policy than older frameworks, when it comes to setting things to null.

When you specifically sets a property type to nullable, .net 6 knows that you do it on purpose. In short you should do:

```
public File? Attachment { get; set; }
```

so asp.net core knows that `null` is okay.

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439479/2210329