# How to ignore empty strings in API JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json, jsonserializer

I have an API developed in .NET6. Currently, all properties that are being returned as null, are being hidden via the below:

```
_ = services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull; });
```

I require to ignore also values that are empty string. There I have implemented the below converter:

```
public class EmptyStringConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetString()!;
    }
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Added the converter to the `AddJsonOptions`:

```
_ = services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new EmptyStringConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

The converter is working - changing empty string properties to null, but in the API response, these properties are visible, although I have set

```
  DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull.
```

I reviewed other articles stating to add the default attribute, but that means having to change all the properties of all the models, which is not feasible. Additionally, this also means that numbers with value 0, will be hidden, which is not something that I would want.

I require to use System.Text.Json rather than Newtonsoft.

Is there a way how I can achieve this please?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10439479/8458649

Comment: @MahdiAnjam thank you for suggestion. I have already looked into this but this suggests to go through all the properties in all response models that I have and add an additional attribute.
To be honest, im already doing something similar to that (my first code snippet) but I require something more dynamic

Comment: this is System.Text.Json - right ? did you try newtonsof json ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic yes correct, this is System.Text.Json. To switch to Newtonsoft, that would mean changing as well attributes that I have associated with model properties and I'm trying to limit the changes that I do at this stage to not break anything.

Comment: maybe you can try and use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.shouldserialize?view=net-8.0. You can define dynamically if property should be serialized.

Comment: @J.Memisevic thank you for your response. I have used your suggestion together with @ pfx to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [customize the JSON contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) used by the `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` or derived type.

Below code changes each property of type `string` to only serialize when not null and not empty.

This contract customization via property type inspection only occurs once per model type. It is the `Func` applied to `ShouldSerialize` that runs for each `string` property value.

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()    
    {
        Modifiers =
        { 
            jsonTypeInfo => 
            {
                foreach (var propertyInfo in jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Where(o => o.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
                {
                    propertyInfo.ShouldSerialize = (parent, property) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(property as string);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is what I need.

I have modified your code slightly so that I will remove the **DefaultIgnoreCondition** and use only the **DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver** for any other type.

`foreach (JsonPropertyInfo? propertyInfo in jsonTypeInfo.Properties)
{
    propertyInfo.ShouldSerialize = (parent, property) => property is string ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(property as string): property is not null;
}`